# Подправить скрипт autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Вот есть скрипт для готовых данных для ввода в поиск

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = ['1', '10000', '100000', '1000000'];
  var firstVal = source[0];
  $("input#priceMin").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: source,
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});
```

и есть скрипт для отправки команды нажатия кнопки поиск

```
$(".priceMin").change(function(){
   $('.search').submit();
});
```

Если пользователь вручную ввел данные, кнопка поиск срабатывает, а если юзер выбрал готовые данные - кнопка поиск не срабатывает. Как сделать чтобы при выборе готовых данных, кнопка поиск срабатывала?

И еще один вопрос: как сделать чтобы в готовых данных отображалось 10 000 руб, а вводились данные 10000 (без пробела и слова руб)?

Comment: В описании плагина есть такая вещь: onSelect: function(data, value){ }, // Callback функция, срабатывающая на выбор одного из предложенных вариантов,

Comment: И еще один вопрос: как сделать чтобы в готовых данных отображалось 10 000 руб, а вводились данные 10000 (без пробела и слова руб)? а это как реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

`$("input#priceMin")` и `$(".priceMin")` - это обращение к разным элементам! у вас есть ОБА? чтобы срабтало, переименуйте свой блок - или классс или ID

Comment: @Grundy ага, действительно. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: @Alex спасибо, понял.